# React native item has a limited height?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have an issue with the react native `<Item>`. Somehow, when it becomes 'too long' it seems to be cut off, which is really weird? This is what is happening currently:

[image: an example of my issue]

As you can see, the blue text under the "wachtwoord" input field half dissapears. It's more visible when I remove the marginTop but it shouldn't be like that. It should just add the extra space and show the full text.

This should also fix the fact that the "wachtwoord" input becomes smaller than the e-mail one (I think).

**The code:**

```
<Grid style={Style.contentContainer}>
          <Row style={Style.content}>
            <Col>
              <View style={Style.completelyCenteredComponent}>
                <Form style={{flex: 1}}>
                   <Item stackedLabel>
                     <Label style={Style.inputLabel}>E-mail (gebruikersnaam)</Label>
                     <Input ref={'usernameInput'} style={Style.stackedInput} />
                   </Item>
                   <Item stackedLabel>
                     <Label style={Style.inputLabel}>Wachtwoord</Label>
                     <Input ref={'passwordInput'} style={Style.stackedInput} />
                     <Text style={Style.textLink}>Wachtwoord vergeten?</Text>
                   </Item>
                </Form>
              </View>

              <View style={{marginTop: 25}}>
                <Button style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
                  <Text>Inloggen!</Text>
                </Button>
              </View>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
```

**And the style**

```
textLink: {
      color: '#2a84d1',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      marginTop: 7,
},

contentContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
},

content: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.88)',
      minWidth: '90%',
      maxWidth: '90%',
      minHeight: 200,
      top: 0,
      borderWidth: 0.6,
      borderColor: '#000000',
      marginTop: 25,
      marginBottom: 20,
      paddingTop: 25,
      paddingBottom: 25,
      flex: 100,
},

completelyCenteredComponent: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'column',
},

inputLabel: {
      color: 'black',
},

stackedInput: {
      minWidth: '96%',
      maxWidth: '96%',
      paddingLeft: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
      borderRadius: 10,
      borderWidth: 0.2,
      borderColor: '#000000',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Button takes too many space. What you are styling is:

under Button is `padding: 25`, top Button is `padding: 25`

The rest of the space go to `completelyCenteredComponent` with `flex: 1`

Your words are disappear is normal because content inside `completelyCenteredComponent` takes more space than it's given.

You could make more space for it with `minHeight: 300` in `content`, or stylist more in `completelyCenteredComponent` or smaller Button.

Comment: Hello, I already have a minHeight:200 in place for `content` so I have increased it to 300, but it sadly didn't fix it. The button is way lower now and between the button and the input is more space, but the text still dissapears and the input field of 'wachtwoord' is also still small.

Comment: Better if you style the text font, and the button. Make the text and button smaller

Comment: When I remove the style for button, it just starts right at the bottom of the half text. It doesn't seem like the button is causing the issue. It's like the `<Form>` doesn't get the proper auto height or something.

Comment: I just tried `<Item stackedLabel style={{minHeight: 75}}>` and that seems to do the trick, but I'm not sure if this is the way it should be done?

Comment: That's the good start. You should put `height` in your `Form` and `fontSize` for the `font/text`. So they should not change on different devices.